# TCL - catching the previous line and compare

Tags: tcl

I have a file with the content.

```
file.txt

interface FastEthernet0/20
 snmp trap mac-notification change added
interface FastEthernet0/21
 snmp trap mac-notification change added
 snmp trap mac-notification change removed
interface FastEthernet0/22
 snmp trap mac-notification change removed
interface FastEthernet0/23
 snmp trap mac-notification change added
 snmp trap mac-notification change removed
interface FastEthernet0/24
 snmp trap mac-notification change added
 snmp trap mac-notification change removed
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
```

I made a script to read this file and, if the interface don't have the two lines "snmp trap mac-notification change added" and "snmp trap mac-notification change removed", I need to put this two commands below the respectively interface.

Expect output:

```
conf t
interface FastEthernet0/20
snmp trap mac-notification change added
snmp trap mac-notification change removed
conf t
interface FastEthernet0/21
snmp trap mac-notification change added
snmp trap mac-notification change removed
conf t
interface FastEthernet0/22
snmp trap mac-notification change added
snmp trap mac-notification change removed
conf t
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
snmp trap mac-notification change added
snmp trap mac-notification change removed
conf t
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
snmp trap mac-notification change added
snmp trap mac-notification change removed
```

The script have 2 problems. One is if the interface have just the line "snmp trap mac-notification change removed", the script skip the block and goes to the next interface till find the block with the three commands (interface,snmp added and snmp removed) or when dont have the two snmp commands. And the other problem, is that when the last line "interface GigabitEthernet0/2" don't have the snmp commands, the script will skip that too.

Here the script.

```
    set intf {}
    set PR {}
    set PPR {}
    set PPRfullintf {}
    set PPRintf {}
    set PRfullintf {}
    set PRintf {}
    set 4 {}
    set P4 {}
    set f [open "file.txt" r]
    foreach a [split [read -nonewline $f] \n] {
        set 1 [lindex $a 1]
        set 0 [lindex $a 0 ]
        set 4 [lindex $a 4 ]

        if { [regexp {^Fa|^Gi} $1] } { set intf1 "interface $1" }

        if { $4 != "added" && $4 != "removed" && $P4 == "added" && $PR == "interface" } {
            puts "conf t\r"
            puts "$PRfullintf\r"
            puts "snmp trap mac-notification change added\r"
            puts "snmp trap mac-notification change removed\r"
        }

        if { $0 == "interface" && $PR == "interface" } {
            puts "conf t\r"
            puts "$PRfullintf\r"
            puts "snmp trap mac-notification change added\r"
            puts "snmp trap mac-notification change removed\r"          
        }
        set P4 $4
        if { $4 == "added" || $4 == "removed" } { set P4 $4 }
        set PR $0
        set PRfullintf $intf1
        set PRintf $1
    }
    close $f
```

Unexpect output:

```
 conf t
 interface FastEthernet0/20
 snmp trap mac-notification change added
 snmp trap mac-notification change removed
 conf t
 interface FastEthernet0/21
 snmp trap mac-notification change added
 snmp trap mac-notification change removed
 conf t
 interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 snmp trap mac-notification change added
 snmp trap mac-notification change removed
```

I think that the attempt to use the command "foreach" to make this, is not appropriate, but I dont found another way to do that. How can I fix all the errors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of text parsing is a lot easier if done in two passes. The following code first registers the "interface" lines in a dictionary and then counts the lines following the "interface" line (0, 1 or 2). I'm assuming that if there are two lines following, one is the "added" line and the other the "removed" line.

In the second pass, the dictionary is traversed and the 0- and 1-count items are printed.

```
set f [open file.txt]
foreach line [split [string trim [chan read $f]] \n] {
    if {[string match interface* $line]} {
        set key $line
        dict set interfaces $key 0
    } else {
        dict incr interfaces $key
    }
}
chan close $f

dict for {key n} $interfaces {
    if {$n < 2} {
        puts "conf t"
        puts $key
        puts "snmp trap mac-notification change added"
        puts "snmp trap mac-notification change removed"
    }
}
```

Documentation: [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: Thanks Mister Peter Lewerin. Exactly what I needed. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same two lines all the time then you can look for `interface` lines only and skip the rest.

```
set data {
interface FastEthernet0/20
 snmp trap mac-notification change added
interface FastEthernet0/21
 snmp trap mac-notification change added
 snmp trap mac-notification change removed
interface FastEthernet0/22
 snmp trap mac-notification change removed
interface FastEthernet0/23
 snmp trap mac-notification change added
 snmp trap mac-notification change removed
interface FastEthernet0/24
 snmp trap mac-notification change added
 snmp trap mac-notification change removed
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
}

set data [split $data "\n"]
set new_data ""

foreach {line} $data {
  if {[string first "interface" $line] != -1} {
    # Found an interface. Add to new_data
    append new_data "conf t\n$line\n"
    append new_data "snmp trap mac-notification change added\n"
    append new_data "snmp trap mac-notification change removed\n"
  }
}

puts $new_data
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @wolfhammer, but that way I will repeat a data that I have. I need to catch just the block with the interface that not contain the two snmp commands or that have just one command.